# Problems on Codeql Github Action workflow, .NET C# Compile with Msbuild return errors than without using codeql not returns

Tags: c#, .net, github-actions, devops

I have the fallowing job in a Github Action Workflow:

```
  build_csharp:
    name: Analyze (C#)
    runs-on: windows-2019
    steps:
    
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Initialize CodeQL
      uses: github/codeql-action/init@v2
      with:
        languages:  'csharp'
    
    - name: Setup MSBuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1

    - name: Localitation1
      if: always()
      shell: powershell
      run: |
        New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" -Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
    - name: Setup NuGet
      uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5
      with:
        nuget-version: "5.1"
    
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.11
    
    - name: Navigate to Workspace
      run: cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
    
    - name: Restore Packages Web
      run: nuget restore app\Belcorp.sln

    - name: Build Solution Web
      shell: powershell
      run: |
          msbuild.exe app\Belcorp.sln /p:DeployWEB=true /p:PublishProfile="PublishAWS.pubxml" /p:Configuration="Release" /p:UseSharedCompilation=true 
    
    - name: Perform CodeQL Analysis
      uses: github/codeql-action/analyze@v2
      with:
        category: "/language:csharp"
```

If I make a compile without the step "Initialize CodeQL" the project build without errors in the step "Build Solution Web". If I  use it, I have errors that in other cases do not have.

Example Error:

[image]

Otherwise:

[image]

I need to be sure if is a feature of Codeql that can check the build, is another wrong configuration or i can just check over the compiled code and avoid this compile check.